# Increase query performance

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm trying to optimize this query:

```
SELECT post_id 
FROM wp_postmeta
WHERE meta_key = 'passenger_group_id'
AND meta_value in (SELECT post_id 
                   FROM wp_postmeta 
                   WHERE meta_key = 'group_event' AND meta_value = '14608')
AND post_id IN (SELECT post_id 
                FROM wp_postmeta 
                WHERE meta_value='Cancelled')
AND post_id NOT IN (SELECT ID 
                    FROM wp_posts 
                    WHERE post_status='trash')
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What concrete **database** is this for? Oracle? MySQL? SQL Server? DB2? Something else entirely? Also: what do your tables look like - what columns (and datatypes!) do they have. How many rows are in those tables? What kind of indexes do you have on your tables? Once you're provided **all of this** - *then* maybe someone can help.....

Comment: @marc_s, those are tables in the Wordpress schema, so this must be MySQL. I've added tags. But your point is right -- people who ask questions should provide DDL for their tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `EXISTS` clause alone and add NOT IN condition can be made `NOT EXISTS`

```
select wp1.post_id 
from wp_postmeta wp1
WHERE meta_key = 'passenger_group_id'
and exists  ( select 1 FROM
              wp_postmeta wp2
              where ( (wp2.meta_key = 'group_event' AND wp2.meta_value = '14608' ) or wp2.meta_value ='Cancelled' )
              and wp2.post_id = wp1.meta_value 

            )
and not exists ( select 1 from
                 wp_posts p
                 on p.id = wp1.post_id
                 and p.post_status = 'trash')
                )
```

Comment: the not in references a different table than what you've done here.  I don't see how this would work given wp_posts isn't in your query.

Comment: @FlawlessData, i think needs more changes, as second not in is from different table